# Register Page View doesnot work in Main Page View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

First of all i have a register page like this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-username form-control", placeholder = "Name" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-username form-control", placeholder = "User Name" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-username form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-username form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn" />
</form>

}
```

and when i try register with that page,i register and add account to database.But i want to use this register page render at Main page and use like that but when i do that it doesn't work.

```
<div class="form-bottom">                    
     @RenderPage("~/Views/User/Register.cshtml")
 </div>
```

and this is the controller code.

```
 public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View(new RegisterModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var siteContext = new SiteContext();
        var user = new User
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Email = model.Email,
            Password=model.Password,
            UserName=model.UserName
        };

        await siteContext.Users.InsertOneAsync(user);
        return RedirectToAction("Profile", "MainPage");
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Problem register page work itself but when i render it at main page it doesn't work.It doesn't add account to database.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error message? If the item is not added to the database then that is the code we need to see.

Comment: Nope there is not.İ can add controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest the whole view is a bit of a mess when you use `Html.BeginForm()` you don't need another `form` inside that. Your view should look like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("{Action}", "{Controller}", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form"})) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-username form-control", placeholder = "Name" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-username form-control", placeholder = "User Name" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-username form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-username form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn" />
}
```

You need to replace `{Action}` with the name of the action, Register. Also replace `{Controller}` with the name of the controller.

Some useful [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29).

Comment: I know i am still newbie at mvc.And thanks it works.